# Automatic Route is not working with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fixed a problem where i had some server code in my client code and now whenever the page loads it doesn't automatically go to home.

The code that specifies to go to Home when the page is loaded is:

`<Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>`

its was working perfectly fine before I mixed up my code and now it doesn't want to work, I deleted a bunch of unnecessary code in other files, I can't imagine how that would affect it though.

Comment: Can you update here the changes made by you, it might help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it:

```js
<Route exact path='/' component={<Home/>}/>

or 

<Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
```

Comment: I did that, that didn't work, it still doesn't go to /home.

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: version number 6.4.3

Comment: Well, the exact props is deprecated, and is your Route at the top of your Routes? The order is important. And what do you mean by "it still doesn't go to /home"? Do you want the URL to be /home ?

Comment: Everything is correctly wrapped, as I said it was working before, and by "/home" i mean localhost:3000/home or thelink.com/home

Comment: You should use Navigate then, something like this:
<Route path={'/'} element={<Navigate to={'/home'} replace />} />